# Object is instantiated at wrong position and every time in the same place

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I'm puzzled, no idea how this is happening... I don't know how my prefab always spawns at the same place even tho I made it set position to the spawner every time. I will put my code from the Spawn script, but I think that can be something in the scene... any ideas? Tell me if you need more info about my scripts etc.

[image]

```
public GameObject prefab, prefab2, prefab3;
public float respawn = 1f;
public float respawn2 = .2f;
public float respawn3 = 50f;
private float rounds = 1f;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    spawne();
    StartCoroutine(invader());
    StartCoroutine(star());
    StartCoroutine(powerup());
}
private void spawne()
{
    GameObject a = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
    a.transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
}
private void spawne2()
{
    GameObject b = Instantiate(prefab2) as GameObject;
    b.transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
}
private void spawne3()
{
    GameObject c = Instantiate(prefab3) as GameObject;
    c.transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
    c.transform.position = transform.position;
    c.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
}
IEnumerator powerup()
{
    while (true)
    {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawn3);
        spawne3();
        if (respawn3 > 5f)
        {
            rounds += 0.2f;
            respawn3 -= 2f * rounds;
        }
        else if (respawn3 < 5f)
        {
            respawn3 = 15f;
        }

    }
}
IEnumerator star()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawn2);
        spawne2();
    }
}
IEnumerator invader()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawn);
        spawne();
    }
}
```

Comment: your prefab objects transform positions are 0,0,0 for everyone? also, you're assign in the transform.position of the object who stores this script, it changes? or is static?

Comment: Will check this out and write back in a minute...

Comment: The object which stores the script changes its position and now All transform positions are the same 0,0,0 - it still doesn't work though. I noticed a second oddity - when the object spawns it changes its scale. I have no idea why....

Comment: they are spawned below any gameObject that changes it's transform?

Comment: Yes, the object changes its transform although the other prefabs are spawning just fine... only this one is giving me a headache. They all should instantiate from the same gameObject.

Comment: I mean, if the instantiated objects are children of the object that changes it's transform, it will affect the childs transform, keep it in mind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214823/discussion-between-hash1-and-lotan).